# Data Frame: row content partial text match in a list , create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, match

Here I am trying to match a list of string in a row content, if in case there is a match, make copy of that string in a new column as a new new variable, below is the reproducible code for the same.

```
import pandas as pd
d2 = {'condn':pd.Series(['4.10 < petal_length <= 5.10','sepal_length > 6.30','1.30 < petal_width <= 1.80','3.00 < sepal_width <= 3.30']),
    'score':pd.Series([2,2,5,3])}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
ref_list = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']
d2
```

**Expected Output (new column : var_name)**

[image: Data frame view]

Here is the code I have tried but wasn't successful.

```
for i in range(0,d2.shape[0]):    
    txt =  temp_data.iloc[i,0]
    if txt.isin(ref_list) :
       d2.ix[i,2] = txt
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: yellow marked column is expected output column  , for every `condn` column row it will check whether the text is there in `ref_list` if yes then take that text and paste into that row of new column names as `var_name`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine the list into a string, with the **OR** separator and run a list comprehension, with **[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)**, to get the matched groups

```
import re
d2['var_name'] = [re.search(fr"{'|'.join(ref_list)}", ent).group()
                 for ent in d2.condn]



        condn                     score var_name
0   4.10 < petal_length <= 5.10     2   petal_length
1   sepal_length > 6.30             2   sepal_length
2   1.30 < petal_width <= 1.80      5   petal_width
3   3.00 < sepal_width <= 3.30      3   sepal_width
```

You could also achieve this with the code below :

```
d2['var_name'] =  d2.condn.str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(ref_list)})")
```

**[F-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)** : they provide an easier (IMO) way to embed values within strings. python has a couple of ways to combine strings with variables, including the **format** method. F-strings just make it easier.

Comment: worked like a smooth cake  , can help me with understanding of  `[re.search(fr"{'|'.join(ref_list)}", ent).group()` this part i didnt understand this

Comment: I added a link to the python docs page on f-strings. allows easier embedding of variable values within strings